AG Grid columnState in redux let ColumnMovedEvent is fired twice
i store the AG Grid columnState into redux when a column is moved but it always reset the order because the columnMoved event is fired twice, first with the new order, second with the old order. If i m not storing the columnState in the redux the event is fired only once and everything works like expected. Any idea want im doing wrong, would be great. Thanks.
Here my code:
  const saveColumnState = (columnState: ColumnState[]) => {
    const copyColumnState: ColumnState[] = [];
    columnState.forEach(c => copyColumnState.push(c))
    dispatch(setGridColumnState({key: props.gridId, columnState: copyColumnState}));

  }
  const saveColumnStateGridConfig = (event: ColumnEvent) => {
    saveColumnState(event.api.getColumnState());
  }

  const saveSortGridConfig = (event: SortChangedEvent) => {
    saveColumnState(event.api.getColumnState());
  }

  const saveColumnMovedGridConfig = (event: ColumnMovedEvent) => {
    if (event.finished) {
      console.log("-----> column moved {}", event.api.getColumnState()[3].colId)
      saveColumnState(event.api.getColumnState());
    }
  }

  const saveFilterGridConfig = (event: FilterChangedEvent) => {
    if (!gridApi) return;
    dispatch(setGridFilterModel({key: props.gridId, filterModel: {...event.api.getFilterModel()}}));
  }

  const onFirstDataRendered = (event: FirstDataRenderedEvent) => {
    if (!gridConfig) return;

    if (gridConfig.columnState) {
      const copyColumnState: ColumnState[] = [];
      gridConfig.columnState.forEach(c => copyColumnState.push(c))

      event.api.applyColumnState({
        state: copyColumnState,
        applyOrder: true
      });
    }

    if (gridConfig.filterModel) {
      event.api.setFilterModel(gridConfig.filterModel);
    }
  }

<AgGridReact<T>
        ...
        onFirstDataRendered={onFirstDataRendered}
        onColumnVisible={saveColumnStateGridConfig}
        onColumnPinned={saveColumnStateGridConfig}
        onColumnResized={saveColumnStateGridConfig}
        onColumnMoved={saveColumnMovedGridConfig}
        onSortChanged={saveSortGridConfig}
        onFilterChanged={saveFilterGridConfig}
        onGridReady={(params) => {
          setGridApi(params.api);
          if (props.onReady) props.onReady(params);
        }}
        ...
      />

Here the reducer code:
interface GridConfigState {
  gridConfigList: GridConfig[];
}

const initialState: GridConfigState = {
  gridConfigList: [],
};

export const gridConfigSlice = createSlice({
  name: "gridConfig",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setGridColumnState: (
      state, action: PayloadAction<{ key: string | undefined, columnState: ColumnState[] }>,
    ) => {
      if (!action.payload.key) return;
      const gridConfig = state.gridConfigList.filter(g => g.key === action.payload.key);
      if (gridConfig && gridConfig.length === 1) {
        gridConfig[0].columnState = action.payload.columnState;
      } else if (!gridConfig || gridConfig.length === 0) {
// Comment this line out, the event is fired only once, dont know why
        state.gridConfigList = [...state.gridConfigList, {
          key: action.payload.key,
          columnState: action.payload.columnState
        }];
      }
    },...

UPDATE:
This is the selector:
export const getGridConfigByKey = (state: RootState, key: string | undefined): GridConfig | undefined => {
  if (!key) return undefined;
  return state.gridConfig.gridConfigList.find(g => g.key === key);
};

And here the use of it:
const gridConfig = useAppSelector((state: RootState) => getGridConfigByKey(state, props.gridId));

So a state change causes a rerender of the Ag Grid with the old column order. When I remove the selector it works fine.
